How to Schedule User-Specific Follow-Up Tasks in Spring Boot with Variable Delays?
How can I implement a system in Spring Boot to schedule follow-up tasks after a user is onboarded? For example:
If User A is onboarded to the system at 12 PM today, an IVR call should be scheduled for 12 PM tomorrow.
If User B is onboarded at 1 PM today, an IVR call should be scheduled for 1 PM tomorrow.
The delay time may vary for each user. What are the different ways to achieve this in Spring Boot? I do not want to use @Schedule annotation.
also tell me if it is possible with kafka and how can i do this task using kafka?

Just to clarify: do you want to implement new spring-boot microservice that should persist some information about when something should happen in the future, and you don't want to pull anything from the repository on a schedule? First of all, i recommend that you to look at quartz

Use a database. Start a cron. Scan for data written in the last X minutes

@snej0keee let me explain usecase again I have 1000 user let say the onboard to our system today at different different time. I want to schedule a IVR call for each user based on their registration time and age.
